# How to debug ssh not connecting on specific port?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, docker

I am trying to connect to a docker that is run on a remote machine using ssh, with the docker exposing its own port 22 as port 2222 on that remote machine.

After

```
docker run -ti --hostname my_docker --name my_docker\
    -p 2222:22 --rm debian bash -c "
        apt update -y;apt install -y openssh-server; service ssh start;
        useradd pi; mkdir -p /home/pi; chown pi /home/pi;
        passwd pi <<< \$'password\npassword'; exec bash"
```

or

```
docker run -ti --hostname my_docker --name my_docker\
    -p 0.0.0.0:2222:22 --rm debian bash -c "
        apt update -y;apt install -y openssh-server; service ssh start;
        useradd pi; mkdir -p /home/pi; chown pi /home/pi;
        passwd pi <<< \$'password\npassword'; exec bash"
```

I can connect **from the remote machine itself to itself** using `ssh -p 2222 pi@<remote_machine_ip>`,

but when trying to connect from a different computer on the same domain using the same `ssh -p 2222 pi@<remote_machine_ip>`, I am getting

> ssh: connect to host <<remote_machine_ip>> port 2222: Connection timed out

---

I am only assuming the problem is port 2222 is not exposed to hosts other than localhost.

1. How to debug this?
2. How to make `ssh -p 2222 pi@<remote_machine_ip>` work from another machine?

Comment: I assume the remote machine is behind some sort of firewall or router? Is port 2222 open to the internet? If the remote machine is behind NAT, is the port forwarded correctly? You also say "from a different computer on the same domain"... Does this mean you are on the same local network? I am confused by your use of the word "domain" in this context.

Comment: @SamForbis I wanted to keep it simpler than it probably has to be: I just checked using `nc -z <remote_machine_ip> 2222; echo $?` that the port is closed (or something else is preventing access). It may be a firewall or something else - **How to check that?** About the domain - I am at home, using a VPN, and connecting via ssh to the remote machine that is in the office. I am not sure I know how to be more specific, so please ask.

Comment: If you are using VPN then it appears you are connecting as if it were on a local network (i.e. NAT and port forwarding do not apply here). I would suspect that the firewall on the remote system is blocking the connection. Depending on the OS/distro of the remote system, you can disable the firewall to test and see if it works. If it works with the firewall disabled, you have isolated the firewall as the source of your connection issue, and you should then re-enable the firewall and create a rule to allow connections on port 2222.

Comment: @SamForbis I am root on the machine, but the IT guy left the company just this week. Is there a way I can check about the firewall? I did `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 2222 --syn -j ACCEPT` which did no good. Does this mean the firewall is external?